# Wait for next page to load then click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid, pageload

I am trying to wait for the next page to load before clicking the next item.

Here is the setup:

First Page

```
var cartbtn = document.getElementById("checkoutButtonFake");
cartbtn.click();
```

Wait for page to load think click this item

```
var checkout = document.getElementById("shippingContinue");
checkout.click();
```

I also know the link for the second page if that helps

Comment: When the next page has loaded, your Javascript is gone.

Comment: @SLaks so the only way to make this work is to put the second part of the code into a second program?

Comment: @DeVonte yes that is the only way

Answer (score 0):

Once the second page loads your first page is gone UNLESS you open the new page in a new window/tab.

The best way to run code once a page load is the jquery document.ready() function, see:
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Put your last part of the code to next page into $.ready function, like this:

second page code

```
$(function(){
   var checkout = document.getElementById("shippingContinue");
   checkout.click();
 })
```